# asp.net mvc 3, add <meta /> to <header> from any part of application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, meta-tags

My question is: How can I add meta tag from my view or partial view? Basically I want to, from the view, write a meta tag, and I want it to be displayed in the header. Is it possible?

Thank you
H

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sections to do this.

In you layout page you need to define the section:

```
<head>
    @RenderSection("Head", required: false)
</head>
```

This section can then be used in any page that uses this layout page:

```
@section Head {
    <meta ... >
}
```